# For WCF - How to return to the client while still processing

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I have a WCF process that uploads a file to the server. Once the file is uploaded then I need to process that file. But I don't want to make the client wait for the processing of that file.

I'm also concerned about multiple request at the same time. I believe that each request spawns a new thread which alleviates that problem. Important: The file names being upload concurrently will not be the same file name.

```
Public Sub RestoreToOps(rFileInfo As RemoteFileInfo) Implements IRestore.RestoreToOps
        Dim oLogItem As New LogItem
        Dim sDestinationFolder As String = My.Settings.DestinationFolder
        Try

            Dim sFileDestination As String = Path.Combine(sDestinationFolder, rFileInfo.FileName)
            If File.Exists(sFileDestination) Then
                File.Delete(sFileDestination)
            End If
            Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(sFileDestination, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read)
                fs.Write(rFileInfo.FileBytes, 0, rFileInfo.FileBytes.Length)
            End Using
            ProcessFile(rFileInfo.FileName)
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    End Sub

<MessageContract>
Public Class RemoteFileInfo
    <MessageHeader>
    Public FileName As String

    <MessageBodyMember(Order:=1)>
    Public FileBytes() As Byte

End Class
```

The client has to wait for the ProcessFile() function to complete before returning to the client. This is unacceptable!
The function ProcessFile() can take as long as 2 minutes to process and longer if there are multiple calls coming in.

Comment: Convert your method to use `async/await` and have the method return `Task<>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some popular options would be:

1. Call `ProcessFile()` on a separate thread

   -- or --
2. Refactor your solution to consist of 3 parts:

   a) Create a work-queue (db) to keep track of files that have been uploaded and need to be processed.

   b) Instead of calling `ProcessFile()`, make a function to "enqueue" the new file into the work-queue.

   c) Make a stand-alone (or scheduled) process to periodically check the queue and process any files in the queue.

The 2nd option is more work, but is a better and more-reliable pattern.  It also gives you more options down-the-road.

Comment: - Would it be okay to spawn a thread from within the WCF process? For each request that comes in to the server, is a new main thread created? I have a solution related to your option #2 but placing all the code in the WCF. Just wondering if this will created a memory leak or threading nightmare... Should I post the code?

Comment: A thread spawned from within the WCF process will keep running within your app pool until completed. Those can be a little more difficult to support or monitor, but only if you get unexpected errors.  Each one will run separately on its own, concurrently.

Comment: It will only cause a resource leak or threading nightmare if you get hung (infinite) processes. Just mind your error handling & logging, maybe add some configurable tracing. Think about exit conditions. Monitor your server memory & thread counts for the first few weeks. You will be reassured that everything is fine.

Comment: That's awesome. Thanks for your help!